# Which of these lenses will work?

Tags: lens, macro-lenses

Which of the following lenses will work best for `macro` with ole m0doel [Olympus E-1](http://www.ebay.com/itm/400735772875?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1439.l2649) camera mentioned [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/400735772875?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1439.l2649)

1. [www.keh.com - OLYMPUS 28MM F/3.5 {49} OLYMPUS - 28 F3.5 (49)](http://www.keh.com/camera/Olympus--Fixed-Focal-Length-Lenses/1/sku-OM060000027500?r=FE)
2. [www.keh.com - OLYMPUS 50MM F/3.5 MACRO {49} OLYMPUS - 50 F3.5 MACRO (49](http://www.keh.com/camera/Olympus--Fixed-Focal-Length-Lenses/1/sku-OM060000082380?r=FE)

Comment: References- [How to take macro photography with Olympus E1](http://www.superstokedmagazine.com/article/2014/02/how-to-take-macro-photography-olympus-e1-macro-lens-settings/)

Answer (score 3):

Lens 2. Its a pseudo macro lens. 1/2 magnification. (true macro is 1/1). And the focal length of it is typical for macro work. (90-105mm FF eq.). The 28mm even with macro extender wouldnt give much of a macro creamy bokeh look.

Comment: I have no idea where this "true macro" idea came from. Traditionally, a "macro lens" was one optimized for reproduction ratios between about 1:4 and 4:1, and if you needed tubes or bellows to get there, then so be it. *Without extra extension*, a 1:2 lens on Micro Four Thirds will give you an image that would have required 1:1 on a full-frame (135 format) camera.

Comment: 1:1 is one to one, whether you have a 1mm sensor or a 10 feet sensor.

Comment: http://www.dpreview.com/articles/6519974919/macro-photography-understanding-magnification "What happens if the subject is the same size in real life as its projection? If we shoot a 1cm fly and its projection on the sensor measures 1cm as well, the magnification is 1:1. The 1:1 ratio has an important meaning for macro enthusiasts. Technically speaking, macro photography means shooting at a magnification ratio of at least 1:1. Therefore, a 'true' macro lens has the ability to produce a magnification ratio of 1:1, or higher."

Comment: If "crop factors" were important in talk about macro, then you could say that a FF with any lens could give you 10:1 or 29:1 if you crop the image. In macro magnification is the major spec. thats why specialty macro lenses like navitar and zeiss use magnification in the spec sheets instead of focal length. It doesnt matter which camera you put them on. It doesnt change the magnification. It just changes your FOV.

Comment: That's perfectly true,  but also, if the smaller format has a higher pixel density, it may indeed be able to record more detail *with less magnification*. That doesn't change the lens, (obviously), but maybe it *should* change the amount of obsession over whether a lens is "true macro" or not. After all, it's the results from the total system that matter.

Comment: the trends Ive seen emerge is (dont know enough optics theory to state this IS the truth): the optics has a tendency to blur before you get to record anything if its not 1:1 squeezing the light is hard. in the link above notice how significantly sharper it gets at 1:1 vs 1:2 and 2:3. thats not the higher pixel count per inch alone that makes this sudden focus. thats also why the same lens performs better on FF than crop even if the crop has same/more pixels.

Comment: I would put a [citation needed] after "[t]echnically speaking, macro photography means shooting at a magnification ratio of at least 1:1". It was never the case historically.

Comment: @MichaelNielsen The difference in those examples is not the sensor size, it is the shooting distance using the same lens/camera. It is quite possible the differences are focusing errors, maybe even intentionally introduced to prove an axe he wanted to grind. Based on some of the other statements in the article I would take the entire thing with a grain of salt. Those who have been around since before digital when 35mm film was the accepted standard for hobbyist/enthusiast macro shooters still cling to the 1:1 *true macro* banner.

Comment: But total magnification includes both the ratio of the virtual image on the sensor *and* the reproduction ratio of the sensor:display size. In the film days the film:display size was pretty well constant (35mm film:8x10print). It is quite possible that some high density cropped sensors can outperform FF sensors in this regard.

Comment: why do you think I think the difference is sensor size? ofc it is distance, duh. thats why min focus distance is important to minimize to achieve 1:1. total magnification? when talking about 1:1 ( or more) macro lenses, everything that goes on after projection through the lens is irrelevant. Magnification by the lens increase quality, magnification after sampling decrease quality (ie dec. resolution, e.g. printing the same image at 300 DPI or 150 DPI). You cant pool those two magnification techniques into one "total mag.". Projecting larger is really the best way to gain IQ.